# iphone stopwatch lap split

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to **split the timer**
means when the timer is running
and there wil be a button below tht timer
when **the button is clicked the current timer time is noted** and the timer continues to proceed frm tht point
and this process repeats

eg stopwatch lap resume

Answer (score 0):

I am an advocate of rectilinear solutions.

```
#import <mach/mach_time.h>

...
NSMutableArray *_stampsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 10];
```

on every 'lap press' save the current system time

```
[_stampsArray addObject: [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong: mach_absolute_time()];
```

and finaly calculate the lap time

```
unsigned int lap = ... // 1 .. n
static struct mach_timebase_info timebase_info;
if(timebase_info.denom == 0) {
  mach_timebase_info(&timebase_info);
}
unsigned long long _timeStampStart = [_stampsArray objectAtIndex: lap -1];
unsigned long long _timeStampStop  = [_stampsArray objectAtIndex: lap];
unsigned long long _timeInterval = _timeStampStop - _timeStampStart;
_timeInterval *= timebase_info.numer;
_timeInterval /= timebase_info.denom;

_timeInterval /= 1000*1000*10; // resolution will be 1/100 sec. now
```

to show the result, you can

```
int _decimalSec = _timeInterval % 100;
int _sec = (_timeInterval / 100) % 60;
int _min = (_timeInterval / (100 * 60)) % 60;
int _hour = (_timeInterval / (100 * 60 * 60));// % 24; 
NSString* formatedAsLapTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d:%02d.%02d", _hour, _min, _sec,_decimalSec];
```

to show the actual elapsed time, just calculate the difference

```
unsigned long long _elapsed = mach_absolute_time() - [_stampsArray objectAtIndex: 0];
```

and use the value in your UI at any regular interval (refresh rate) as You want. There is a good place to use NSTimer :-)